# Updating a TableRow using a CheckBox in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am making an App that has a TableView. This TableView has 4 columns, of which the first column uses a CheckBox. The data displayed in the TableView is from a Bill class with name, dateDue and Amount making up the other 3 columns.
When the CheckBox is selected (which is the default on start up) all the bills in the Table are displayed in white colour. When a CheckBox is unselected, the bill on that row needs to be 'ghosted' or change the colour of the characters.

In my fxml file I have used the code:

```xml
<TableColumn prefWidth="49.0" text="On/Off" fx:id="checkBoxSelectionColumn">
    <cellValueFactory>
        <BillsCheckBox/>
    </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

The associated BillCheckBox class:

```java
public class BillsCheckBox implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Bill, CheckBox>, ObservableValue<CheckBox>> {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<CheckBox> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Bill, CheckBox> param) {
        Bill bill = param.getValue();
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.selectedProperty().setValue(true);
        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> {
            if(bill.isSelected() == false) {
                bill.setSelected(true);

            } else {
                bill.setSelected(false);
            }
        });
        return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(checkBox);
    }
}
```

In the controller class:

```java
billsTable.setRowFactory(row -> new TableRow<Bill>(){
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Bill bill, boolean empty){
        super.updateItem(bill, empty);

        if (bill == null || empty) {
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            //Now 'bill' has all the info of the Bill in this row
            if (bill.isSelected() == true) {
                //We apply now the changes in all the cells of the row
                for(int i=0; i<getChildren().size();i++){
                    ((Labeled) getChildren().get(i)).setTextFill(Color.GRAY);
                }
                //totalLabel.setText(String.format("%.2f", data.finalBillsTotal(bill.getAmount()))); // Update bill total - ** needs work
            } else if(bill.isSelected() == false){
                if(getTableView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().contains(bill)){
                    for(int i=0; i<getChildren().size();i++){
                        ((Labeled) getChildren().get(i)).setTextFill(Color.WHITE);;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The CheckBox on each row of the table is selected correctly. When one is unselected, the corresponding row characters change colour, but when another row is unselected, the previous row reverts back to its original colour. JavaFX is new to me so still trying to grasp the concepts. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't use the `cellValueFactory` to determine the visual representation of the table cell. That's the responsibility of the `cellFactory`. The `cellValueFactory` only exposes the data itself.

There already exists a `TableCell` implementation + factory for this purpose: [`CheckBoxTableCell`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html).

The following code assumes your `Bill` class provides a `selectedProperty` method providing a `BooleanProperty` containing the value of the `selected` property (modified on a call of `setSelected`).

```
checkBoxSelectionColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().selectedProperty());
checkBoxSelectionColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(checkBoxSelectionColumn));
```

For modifying the look of the row I recommend using CSS and `PseudoClass`:

```
final PseudoClass ghosted = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("ghosted");

billsTable.setRowFactory(row -> new TableRow<Bill>(){

    private final InvalidationListener l = o -> {
        pseudoClassStateChanged(ghosted, getItem().isSelected());
    };
    private final WeakInvalidationListener listener = new WeakInvalidationListener(l);

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Bill bill, boolean empty){
        // remove listener from last item
        Bill oldItem = getItem();
        if (oldItem != null) {
            oldItem.selectedProperty().removeListener(listener);
        }

        super.updateItem(bill, empty);

        if (bill == null || empty) {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(ghosted, false);
        } else {
            // add listener & update
            bill.selectedProperty().addListener(listener);
            l.invalidated(null);
        }
    }
});
```

This allows you to modify the cell style from a css stylesheet added to the `TableView`, one of its ancestors or the scene containing the table:

```css
.table-row-cell:ghosted .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: gray;
}
```

This has the additional benefit of allowing you to specify a different style for selected rows:

```css
.table-row-cell:ghosted:selected .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the use of CellValueFactory , CellFactory and CheckBoxTableCell. I am going investigate those more. You code helped me overcome the problem.